# ¿Por que al crear un projecto nuevo de django en visual studio 2019, se crea con la vesion 2.1.2 y no la mas actual?

Tags: django

Tengo instalado django 3.2.6, pero al crear el proyecto desde la opcion que da visual estudio, se crea con la version 2.1.2

Configuración de Django para el proyecto DjangoWebProject4.

Basado en 'django-admin startproject' usando Django 2.1.2.

Para obtener más información sobre este archivo, consulte https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

Para obtener la lista completa de configuraciones y sus valores, consulte https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/ "" "

Comment: Hola @YoelRomeropty, intentaste utilizando el comando `pipenv install django==3.0.2`?

Comment: Hola, lo utilice pero no funciono, los proyectos se siguen creando con django 2.12.

Comment: Que version de python tienes en tu PC

Comment: Tengo la version 3.9.0.